# How to assign a function to a variable without executing it?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to create a variable that can be assigned a function, but the function is executed while assigning the variable. How does one assign the function to the variable without executing it?

```
object VariableMethod {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    (new VariableMethod).test()
  }
}

class VariableMethod {
  var method: Unit = _
  def f1() {
    println("Executing f1")
  }
  def test() {
    method = f1 // Method f1 is invoked on this line, I only want the assignment to occur on this line
    println("Is f1 executed before or after this?")
    method // I want the f1 method to be invoked only here.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...

```
object VariableMethod {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    (new VariableMethod).test()
  }
}

class VariableMethod {
  var method: () => Unit = _
  def f1() {
    println("Executing f1")
  }
  def test() {
    method = f1
    println("Is f1 executed before or after this?")
    method()
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: do you understand why this is the case? If so, it would be beneficial for the community if you'd expand your answer to include this information.

Answer (score 1):

When the function has no args and you want to assign it to a `val` or `var`, you can use the `_` notation to indicate that you want to partially apply it.  So for example:

```
object TestFunc{

  def f1() = {
    "foo"
  }

  val v1 = f1 _
  val v2 = f1 
  val v3 = v1()
}
```

In this example, v1 is of type `() => String` and v2 is of type `String`.  For `v3`, we fully apply `v1` and end up with a `String` which would the the same as `v2`.